# install calibre 1.0 ebook library

Tags: 13.04, calibre

How to install calibre 1.0 in Ubuntu 13.04 ?

Comment: I use flatpak to install calibre, for what it's worth..

Answer (score 2):

Open your terminal and type these lines one by one in your terminal.

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/calibre
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install calibre
```

Comment: The [PPA you mention](http://launchpad.net/~n-muench/+archive/calibre) currently only has versions 0.9.25 & 0.9.41. Although it does appear to be active. I imagine that it will be updated to 1.0 shortly.

Comment: Yeah I have read that at webupd8 blog in todays article.

Answer (score 2):

Since the available version of Calibre in the repositories is usually outdated, the author(s) of Calibre recommend installing the software from the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) using the following command:

```
sudo python -c "import sys; py3 = sys.version_info[0] > 2; u = __import__('urllib.request' if py3 else 'urllib', fromlist=1); exec(u.urlopen('http://status.calibre-ebook.com/linux_installer').read()); main()"
```

One can also avoid having the installer script ask for the installation directory by specifying it in the install command itself, as shown below:

```
sudo python -c "import sys; py3 = sys.version_info[0] > 2; u = __import__('urllib.request' if py3 else 'urllib', fromlist=1); exec(u.urlopen('http://status.calibre-ebook.com/linux_installer').read()); main(install_dir='/path/to/your/library')"
```

Note that you will need to specify the desired location of your ebook library for the `install_dir` parameter.

Due to the nature and number of dependencies, the author ***does not recommend*** to installing this application from its source files, or from your distributions' repositories.

[Source](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux)

Comment: Thanks for adding one more answer. I am actually trying let the other users to know about recent version release.

Comment: The command on the calibre website appears to be different now: https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux